# Create a Map from XML by extracting elements of with same tag

Tags: xml, scala

Below is my XML. I want to create a `Map[String,String]` with key is first one in cell and value is second value, e.g. `Map["Active" -> "A","Cancelled"->"c"......]`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dvm name="Mapping" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/dvm">
  <description>
  </description>
  <columns>
    <column name="XXXX"/>
    <column name="YYYY"/>
  </columns>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <cell>Active</cell>
      <cell>A</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell>Cancelled</cell>
      <cell>C</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell>Suspended</cell>
      <cell>S</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell>Reserved</cell>
      <cell>R</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell>N/A</cell>
      <cell>N</cell>
    </row>
  </rows>
</dvm>
```

Comment: I suggest that you get a piece of paper and a pencil. Write **in words** the steps that you need to take to solve the problem. After you have a clear understanding of these steps, then translate them into code.

Comment: please fix your formatting. also a small google search would point you to existing guides on working with scala and XML.
[like this one](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/xml-parsing-xpath-extract-xml-tag-attributes)

Comment: Looks like a well-asked question to me, just needed a little editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val table =
  <dvm name="Mapping" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/dvm">
    <description>
    </description>
    <columns>
      <column name="XXXX"/>
      <column name="YYYY"/>
    </columns>
    <rows>
      <row>
        <cell>Active</cell>
        <cell>A</cell>
      </row>
      <row>
        <cell>Cancelled</cell>
        <cell>C</cell>
      </row>
      <row>
        <cell>Suspended</cell>
        <cell>S</cell>
      </row>
      <row>
        <cell>Reserved</cell>
        <cell>R</cell>
      </row>
      <row>
        <cell>N/A</cell>
        <cell>N</cell>
      </row>
    </rows>
  </dvm>

val cells = for ( row <- table \\ "row") yield (for (cell <- row \ "cell" ) yield cell.text) match {
  case Seq(k,v) => (k,v)
}
cells.toMap
```

Comment: @Chandra Good. Perhaps you would consider accepting it as the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

If your xml is defined in code like the following (please note that you don't really want the first line):

```
val xml = //<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dvm name="Mapping" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/dvm">
  <description>
...
```

then you can use the following snippet to convert it to map:

```
  val map = ((xml \\ "row") map { row =>
    val pair = row \ "cell" map { cell =>
      cell.text
    }
    pair(0) -> pair(1)
  }).toMap
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest way to do it, assuming the example XML file is `dvm.xml`.

```
val dvm: scala.xml.Elem = scala.xml.XML.loadFile("dvm.xml")

val rows: Seq[Seq[String]] = {
  for {
    rows <- dvm \ "rows"
    row <- rows \ "row"
  } yield {
    for {
      cell <- row \ "cell"
    } yield {
      cell.text
    }
  }
}

val cells: Seq[(String, String)] = 
  for ( Seq(k, v) <- rows )
  yield (k -> v)

val mappings: Map[String, String] = cells.toMap

val a: String = mappings("Active")
val c: String = mappings("Cancelled")
val r: String = mappings("Reserved")
val n: String = mappings("N/A")
```

This is intentionally quick and dirty.  If you want to handle cases where there aren't two cell elements or other various error conditions, you should start a new question and ask that, and provide the source code you use.

Here is the scala-xml wiki which has some more examples, now:

https://github.com/scala/scala-xml/wiki