# How can I parse the below XML format in scala

Tags: xml, scala

```
<nv n="1" v ="a"/><nv n="2" v ="b"/><nv n="3" v ="c"/><nv n="4" v ="d"/>
output:
(4,d)
```

I am new to scala and I am trying to parse an XML file. I am having the above xml format. I need to get the particular tag output like (4,d) as a pair.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47912314/create-a-map-from-xml-by-extracting-elements-of-with-same-tag

Comment: You're missing a root element in the example XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare multiple XML elements as a `NodeSeq`:

```
val xml: scala.xml.NodeSeq = <nv n="1" v ="a"/><nv n="2" v ="b"/><nv n="3" v ="c"/><nv n="4" v ="d"/>
```

You can convert that XML to pairs with:

```
scala> val pairs = for { nv <- xml } yield { nv\@"n" -> nv\@"v" }
pairs: Seq[(String, String)] = List((1,a), (2,b), (3,c), (4,d))
```

There's a chance your XML is in a root element, like so:

```
val xml: scala.xml.NodeSeq = <root>
  <nv n="1" v ="a"/>
  <nv n="2" v ="b"/>
  <nv n="3" v ="c"/>
  <nv n="4" v ="d"/>
</root>
```

If the file is in a root element, then get it as such:

```
scala> val pairs = for { nv <- xml \ "nv" } yield { nv\@"n" -> nv\@"v" }
pairs: Seq[(String, String)] = List((1,a), (2,b), (3,c), (4,d))
```

If you wrote to read the XML file, use:

```
val xml: Elem = scala.xml.XML.loadFile("nv.xml")
```

Answer (score -1):

You may do this by following way. To learn it [refer](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-extract-data-from-xml-nodes-in-scala)

```
scala> val xml = <nv n="1" v ="a"/><nv n="2" v ="b"/><nv n="3" v ="c"/><nv n="4" v ="d"/>
xml: scala.xml.NodeBuffer = ArrayBuffer(<nv n="1" v="a"/>, <nv n="2" v="b"/>, <nv n="3" v="c"/>, <nv n="4" v="d"/>)

scala> val lastElement = (xml \\ "nv").last
lastElement: scala.xml.Node = <nv n="4" v="d"/>

scala> (lastElement \ "@n", lastElement \ "@v")
res24: (scala.xml.NodeSeq, scala.xml.NodeSeq) = (4,d)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use `scala.xml.XML` to load xml from the file and access the nodes as you want.

Given input as string xml (*I added  node since your example does not have root node*),

```
scala> val xmlData = """<root><nv n="1" v ="a"/><nv n="2" v ="b"/><nv n="3" v ="c"/><nv n="4" v ="d"/></root>"""
xmlData: String = <root><nv n="1" v ="a"/><nv n="2" v ="b"/><nv n="3" v ="c"/><nv n="4" v ="d"/></root>
```

Load the xml string,

```
scala> val xmlNodes = scala.xml.XML.loadString(xmlData)
xmlNodes: scala.xml.Elem = <root><nv v="a" n="1"/><nv v="b" n="2"/><nv v="c" n="3"/><nv v="d" n="4"/></root>
```

Now, since `<nv>` is the child of root node, get the last of child nodes

```
scala> val nodeIwant = xmlNodes.child.last
nodeIwant: scala.xml.Node = <nv v="d" n="4"/>
```

And then access the `attribute` which gives you `Option(result)`,

```
scala> (nodeIwant.attribute("v"), nodeIwant.attribute("n"))
res1: (Option[Seq[scala.xml.Node]], Option[Seq[scala.xml.Node]]) = (Some(d),Some(4))
```

You can use `.attributes` to get the values only,

```
scala> (nodeIwant.attributes("v"), nodeIwant.attributes("n"))
res2: (Seq[scala.xml.Node], Seq[scala.xml.Node]) = (d,4)
```